# How to send data in real time using freertos

Tags: real-time, tcp, freertos, zynq

I’m really new on the coding world and I need your help. I need to do the following:
In a Zedboard platform I take data from a USB port and want to make real time packets and send them via TCP.

I have establish FreeRTOS for that. I take the data from a UART and keep them in a cycle buffer. I send a TCP command from Matlab for starting the transmission but that gives me just one packet of data. How a make this real time?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't understand your question - you mention both USB and UART - is the USB a virtual COM port?  Whether its a UART of a USB port, once the received data is placed in the buffer you can use something like a [direct to task notification](http://www.freertos.org/RTOS-task-notifications.html) to unblock a higher priority task to then send that data over the TCP link.

There is a FreeRTOS/Zynq/TCP example on the following link: http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_TCP/TCPIP_FAT_Examples_Xilinx_Zynq.html